# How to display image in jquery-bootgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-bootgrid

I am using **jquery-bootgrid** for display list of records.

These records have image also but images are not display in rows.

Anybody knows how to display images in rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use formatters. Below is an example. Here, data is loaded from the database via ajax:

```
<table id="gridStudents" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-column-id="StudentId" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">Student Id</th>
                <th data-column-id="FirstName">First Name</th>
                <th data-column-id="LastName">Last Name</th>
                <th data-column-id="Photo" data-formatter="pix">Photo</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

Then, in your javascript, do the following (assuming you have a controller named Student and 2 actions named getStudents and getPhoto(int StudentId), which respectively fetch all the students and get the photograph of a specific student based on his or her StudentId)  :

```
$(function () {  
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
         url: 'Student/getStudents',
         type: 'POST'
    });
    jqxhr.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#gridStudents").bootgrid({
            caseSensitive: false,
            selection: true,
            multiSelect: true,
            formatters: {                    
                "pix": function (column, row) {
                    return "<img src=\"Student/getPhoto/" + row.StudentId + "\" />";
                    }
                }
        }).bootgrid("append", data)
    });
});
```

Below is what the server side would look like. Here the photos are stored as binary data in a field named Photo in the database, and another field named ContentType stores the content type (image/jpeg, image/png, etc.):

```
[Authorize]
public class StudentController : Controller
{ 
    .... //your other stuff....

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult getStudents()
    {
        var data = db.Students.ToList();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult getPhoto(int StudentId)
    {
        var student = db.Students.Find(StudentId);
        return File(student.Photo, student.PhotoContentType);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a formatter to do the conversion to an image tag:

```
$("#grid-data").bootgrid({
    formatters: {
        "imageCol": function(column, row) {
             return "<img src='" + row.id + "' />";
        }
    }
});
```

where "imageCol" is the column that holds the absolute path to your image.

Comment: data should be bind dynamically so how can I do that ? I want to bind data from modal.